# How to extend from native constructor typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class ExtendSet<T> extends Set<any> {
  constructor(value: any) {
    super(value);
  }
}

var s = new ExtendSet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

console.log(s);
```

**TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'**

actually, I just want to extend Set Object some method,like toArray():any[]

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "mocha",
      "node",
      "typescript",
      "core-js"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting this error. If you go to [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ExtendSet%3CT%3E%20extends%20Set%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(value)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20s%20%3D%20new%20ExtendSet(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(s)%3B) playground snippet you'll see that it throws no error. Perhaps you are using an outdated version of typescript.

As to the thing you are trying to achieve:

*I just want to extend Set Object some method,like toArray():any[]*

An easier way would be to do the following:

```
interface Set<T> { 
    toArray: () => any
}

Set.prototype.toArray = () => { 
    // write your code here
}
```

Comment: I want extend a new class from Set class,not write on origin constructor